# Integration and determining the impact velocity.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, hyperbolic-functions

Question: Man jumps from an airplane at an altitude of h metres. Determine the impact velocity upon landing. Express it in terms of $h$.

$$v  = \sqrt{5g} \cdot \tanh\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{5}}t\right)$$

Attempt to solve:

I first integrate it to get:

$$h(t) = 5\sqrt{g} \cdot \ln\left(\cosh \left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{5}}t\right)\right)+C$$

Then from the question, I got the condition h=h when $t=0$, thus:

$$h(t) = 5\sqrt{g} \cdot \ln\left(\cosh \left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{5}}t\right)\right)+h$$

Then I am stuck. I think impact velocity is velocity when $h=0$ but I am not sure.

Do tell me if information is not sufficient to solve this problem.

Edit: Velocity at time t with the downwards direction is taken as positive.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity is toward the ground so if you're defining $h(0) = h$ and that impact is when $h(t) =0$ you want to use the equation $$ h(t) = h-5\sqrt{g}\ln\left(\cosh\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{5}}t\right)\right)$$ for the height.

Comment: Can you explain the equation?

Comment: Ohh, I get what you mean now

Comment: Since you want to orient up to be the positive direction, you need the velocity to be negative, since they are moving downward.